# Angular5 - translate expressions or text in TS File for localization?

Tags: angular5, angular-i18n

In my angular5 application, i am trying to make everything localized and translated. I am following steps mentioned in this link: https://angular.io/guide/i18n

Question:

- How to mark text with i18n tag for text in TS files?

For example:

The text in the name field of array needs to be translated:

```
pageList = [
    { id: 1, path: '/dashboard', name: 'Dashboard' },
    { id: 2, path: '/list', name: 'List' }
  ]
```

This array is used in the dropdown:

```
<button class="dropdown-item" *ngFor="let page of pageList" (click)="changePage(page.path)">{{ page.name }}</button>
```

How to mark text displayed in an expression to be translated?
For example:

```
<h1 lass="page-title">{{ pageTitle }}</h1>
```

Thanks!